# Postgres XML parse nodename

Tags: xml, postgresql, parsing, nodename

I have some XML like this:

```
<title>A Closer Look</title>
<pubDate>Thu, 12 Sep 2019 17:46:49 +0000</pubDate>
<language>en</language>
<copyright><![CDATA[]]></copyright>
<category:keywords>business,businessnews</category:keywords>
```

I am using this query to parse the XML:

```
SELECT (xpath('//channel/title/text()', x))[1]::varchar AS Title,
       (xpath('//channel/pubDate/text()', x))[1]::varchar AS PublishDate,
       (xpath('//channel/language/text()', x))[1]::varchar AS Language,
       (xpath('//channel/copyright/text()', x))[1]::varchar AS Copyright,
       (xpath('//channel/category:keywords']/text()', x))[1]::varchar AS CategoryKeywords
FROM unnest(xpath('//channel', pg_read_file('test.xml')::xml)) x;
```

However, I am getting this error doe to the colon:

```
ERROR:  could not create XPath object
DETAIL:  Undefined namespace prefix
```

How can I perform this query including the node name with the colon

Thank!

Answer (score 0):

You need a namespace declaration for the 'category'. Try putting this in the root element of your XML:

```
<root xmlns:category="tempuri.org">
```

-You haven't included your whole XML so I have called the element 'root' - but you dont' need to change that.

Comment: Is there no other way?   I ask only because, we get this XML file in from an external client, so we must work with whatever they give us.

Comment: Can you first  test whether this fixes it, then work out how to implement it?